# I'm getting this error map is not a function error

Tags: reactjs

This is my code:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/esm/Button'

const BookingScreen = () => {
  const [room, setRoom] = useState([])
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState()
    const location = useLocation()
  
    const path = location.pathname.split("/",5)[4]
  
    useEffect(() => {
   
      fetchData()
    },[])

    const fetchData = async () => {
      const res = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/room/" + path)
      setRoom(res.data)
      console.log(res.data)
      setLoading(false)
  }
   
    const singleRoom =  room.map((item) => {
      return (
        <div key={item._id} >
          <div className="row justify-content-md-center mt-4 ">
            <div className="col-md-6">
              <img src={item.imageUrl
              [0]
              } alt="singleRoom" />
            </div>
            <div className="col-md-4">
              <h2>{item.name}</h2>
              <p>{item.desc}</p>
              <p>Category : {item.categoy}</p>
              <Button variant="secondary">
                 Book Now </Button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      )
    }) 
 
    return (
      <>
       {loading ? <h1>Loading ...</h1> : singleRoom}
      </>
    )
}

export default BookingScreen
```

I'm trying to populate the list `singleRoom` but it keeps saying map is not a function when I console data I'm getting everything and after that, I used `setRoom` hook to set the data, but somehow it's empty.

Comment: does `await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/api/room/" + path).data` definitely resolve to an array?

Comment: `map()` is a available on arrays. Are you sure the data you are getting from the request is an array? Can you add the console.log output to your question

Comment: you could do (room || []) to see if that resolves it if so then like the others said your data is not in fact an array

Answer (score 0):

Things i would say, is that if the data returns as an array then its fine, otherwise you'll need to change your logic of return.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/esm/Button'


const BookingScreen = () => {
    const [room, setRoom] = useState([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true) // set to true by default
    const location = useLocation()

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()
    }, [])

    const fetchData = async () => {
        const path = location.pathname.split("/", 5)[4]
        setLoading(true)
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(`http://localhost:5000/api/room/${path}`)
            if (res.data) {
                setRoom(res.data); // does this actually return an array? 
                setLoading(false)
            } else {
                setRoom([]) // force back an empty array if data wasn't returned
                setLoading(false)
            }
        } catch (err) {
            setRoom([]) // set back to empty
            setLoading(false)
            // I'd usually also do an error state here.
        }
    }

    const singleRoom = room.length > 0 ? room.map(({ _id, imageUrl, name, desc, categoy }) => (
        <div key={_id} >
            <div className="row justify-content-md-center mt-4 ">
                <div className="col-md-6">
                    <img src={imageUrl
                    [0]
                    } alt="singleRoom" />
                </div>
                <div className="col-md-4">
                    <h2>{name}</h2>
                    <p>{desc}</p>
                    <p>Category : {categoy}</p>
                    <Button variant="secondary">
                        Book Now </Button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
    ) : <div>No room data found</div>


    return (
        <>
            {loading ? <h1>Loading ...</h1> : singleRoom}
        </>
    )
}

export default BookingScreen
```

Comment: If it is a "SINGLE ROOM" as in there is only 1 return and its not of type array, you need to remove the map and just use the data return as `room._id` for instance.